# small question on js syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I saw this syntax many times but I couldn't find a way to google it properly, I hope I can get some help here:

```
  <script>
    (function(){
      //code goes here
    })();
  </script>
```

Why is the function keyword wrapped in the parenthesis? What does it do and what is this called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In js, the syntax:

```
function() { //code }
```

defines an anonymous function.  You can store this into a variable and call it:

```
var a = function() { //code };
a();
```

or if you don't want to bother assigning it you can do it in one step.

```
(function() { //code })();
```

the parenthesis are necessary because:

```
function() { //code }();
```

is not proper syntax.

This syntax is useful in certain situations to help memory management as well as change variable names.  For example in javascript you have a `jQuery` object, but most people refer to it as `$`.  But sometimes `$` is used as some other variable instead of the jQuery object.  To fix this, you can wrap your code in:

```
(function($) { // code that uses $ })(jQuery);
```

That way you can use the dollar sign and not have to worry whether or not it actually points to the jQuery object or not.

Comment: I prefer Tomalak's explanation, the main purpose of using such constructs is creating closures to avoid leaking variables in the global scope.

Comment: @Bob, thank you for your detailed explanation. Just one more thing, so the code inside the function will be executed instantly if it isn't assigned to a variable?

Comment: @Nik: Only if you call it afterwards (by appending `()` to it).

Comment: @thejh Got it! In that case I can't imagine why anyone wouldn't run it immeidately and NOT assign it to a variable for reference for use later

Comment: @Nik: Yes, that would be dumb to just declare it for no reason.  You either call it, pass it into a function, or assign it to a variable.

Comment: Even though the return value of the function is not assigned to a variable, the closure will be maintained.  It's useful for storing state - often used for storing default configuration for libraries.

Answer (score 5):

It is called an anonymous function that is being called immediately.

```
// defining and calling a named function
function x() { /* do something */ }
x();

// defining an anonymous function (usually to assign it to a variable)
var x = function () { /* do something */ };
x();

// defining and calling an anonymous function in one step 
(function () { /* do something */ })();
```

Most often the last pattern is used as part of creating a closure.

Answer (score 2):

You can google (or search on Stack Overflow) JavaScript `anonymous function` or `closure`

Some links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function
- http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: thanks for the links! And more importantly the names for these syntaxes

Answer (score 1):

See Bob Fincheimers answer for an explaination of what it means.

It is used to wrap a bunch of functions and variables that the programmer doesn't want to be visible from the outside - that's good when you're using libraries or so, you don't want them to block many function names for internal stuff.